# Consulta en LINQ demora tiempo en ser completada (no siempre pasa)

Tags: asp.net, linq, blazor

Perdón por no se más especifico en el título. No quería que fuera un título largo y para nada descriptivo.
En mi trabajo tenemos una App donde realizamos consultas, registramos y editamos información. Está desarrolla con Blazor Server .Net core 5. Corre bajo IIS en una Intel i5 con 16 RAM y disco SSD. La base de datos es SQL EXPRESS 2017.
Es una implementación local, por lo que no hay consultas fuera de la red interna. En ese servidor hay un disco compartido para almacenar documentos también. A la App no entran mas de 5 personas a la vez o no siempre hacen el mismo tipo de consultas.

Lo que ocurre no siempre pasa, pero algunas veces cuando pasa una búsqueda tarda mas de 20 segundos en completarse. Algunas veces mas, otras veces menos. Pero no siempre. La mayoría de las veces es casi instantanea la respuesta.
Por eso necesito consultar en donde está el error, o que tipo de pruebas debo hacer para conocer y tratar de mejorar la consulta.

El código que escribí es el siguiente. La `opción` es la elección del usuario sobre que tipo de datos quiere buscar. Esas opciones claramente están en la página razor (las validaciones las hago en el cliente).

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Carpeta>> GetCarpetasAsync(string search, string opcion)
    {
        
        if (opcion == "NroCarpeta")
        {
            var query = await _context.Carpetas
                .Include(s => s.Cliente)
                    .Where(s => s.NroCarpeta == Convert.ToInt32(search))
                    .OrderBy(s => s.NroCarpeta)
                    .ToListAsync();
            
            return query;
        }
        if (opcion == "ClienteCarpeta")
        {
            
            var separador = search.Split("/");

            int nroCliente = Convert.ToInt32(separador[0]);
            int nroCarpeta = Convert.ToInt32(separador[1]);

            var query = await _context.Carpetas
                .Include(s => s.Cliente)
                .Where(s => s.Cliente.NroCliente == nroCliente && s.NroCarpeta == nroCarpeta)
                .ToListAsync();

            return query;
                                
        }
        if (opcion == "Caratula")
        {
            var searchUp = search.ToUpper();

            var query = await _context.Carpetas
                .Include(s => s.Cliente)
                .Where(s => s.Caratula.Contains(searchUp))
                .OrderBy(s => s.Caratula)
                    .ThenByDescending(s => s.FechaAlta)
                .ToListAsync();

            return query;
                            
        }

        return null;
    }
```

**EDIT** (agrego el modelo Carpeta y Cliente)

```
public class Carpeta
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int NroCarpeta { get; set; }
    public string Caratula { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaAlta { get; set; }
    public string Abogado { get; set; }
    public string NroExpediente { get; set; }
    public string TipoProceso { get; set; }
    public string Fuero { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FechaDemanda { get; set; }
    public bool Judicial { get; set; }
    public bool ExtraJudicial { get; set; }
    public string Provincia { get; set; }
    public string Ciudad { get; set; }
    public bool Baja { get; set; }
    public string Observacion { get; set; }
    public string CampoAuxiliar1 { get; set; }
    public string CampoAuxiliar2 { get; set; }
    public string CampoAuxiliar3 { get; set; }
    public string Responsabilidad { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FechaDespido { get; set; }
    public string NroSiniestro { get; set; }
    public string NroDemanda { get; set; }
    public string EstudioId { get; set; }
    public bool NoInformar { get; set; }
    public string GoogleFolderId { get; set; }
    public int? Cuerpo { get; set; }
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    public int? JuzgadoId { get; set; }
    public Juzgado Juzgado { get; set; }


    public Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    public Contraparte Contraparte { get; set; }
    public BajaCarpeta BajasCarpeta { get; set; }
    public Economico Economicos { get; set; }
    public Conciliado Conciliados { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Movimiento> Movimientos { get; set; }
}

public class Cliente
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int NroCliente { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaAlta { get; set; }
    public string NombreCliente { get; set; }
    public string Domicilio { get; set; }
    public string Telefono { get; set; }
    public string TelefonoAlternativo { get; set; }
    public long CUIT { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Responsable { get; set; }
    public string ModoCalculoCarpeta { get; set; }
    public string EstudioJuridicoId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Carpeta> Carpetas { get; set; }

}
```

Espero se entienda la consulta. En si no hay error, solo que algunas veces tarda mucho en responder. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

> Lo que ocurre no siempre pasa, pero algunas veces cuando pasa una búsqueda tarda mas de 20 segundos en completarse. Algunas veces mas, otras veces menos. Pero no siempre. La mayoría de las veces es casi instantanea la respuesta.

Me parece importante para este caso que compartas más información como los modelos "Carpeta" y "Cliente", al igual que un aproximado del número de registros que tiene cada tabla. Dicho esto, y basandome solo en el código que compartes, me atrevo a decir que las consultas son lentas cuando los usuarios escogen la opción "Caratula". Esto debido a que para cada registro de la tabla "Carpeta", estás preguntando si la columna "Caratula" contiene el término de busqueda.

Dale un vistazo a [esto](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Hola @Giancarlo, gracias por responder. Agregue los modelos `Carpeta` y `Cliente`. Con respecto a lo que supones, la mayoria de los usuarios escogen buscar por `Caratula`, por lo que no podrías confirmar si pasa lo mismo con las otras opciones.

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso el problema era que en el mismo servidor también corría el servidor de Power BI (una prueba que se estuvo haciendo) al deshabilitar los servicios ahora la App corre bien y en el tiempo esperados.
Muchas gracias por leer.
Saludos.